# RadioButtonList with image throwing XXS error on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, radio-button

I have managed to add an image to a radio button by the following code

```
themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='ThemeImages/blue.png'>","fsd")));
themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='ThemeImages/green.png'>")));
themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='ThemeImages/red.png'>")));
```

works fine. However due to the html gives a cross side scripting alert. Anyway around this?

Comment: What for do you use `String.Format()` here?

Comment: I got the code off a friend... thanks a lot.. works fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with :

```
themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", "ThemeImages/blue.png") ,"fsd"));

themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", "ThemeImages/green.png") ));

themeRadioButtonList.Items.Add(
    new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", "ThemeImages/red.png") ));
```