# Adding images to RadioButtonList causes error on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have RadioButtonList, in which I am adding images dynamically:

```
this.RlCredtiCardTypes.Items.Add(new ListItem(String.Format("<img src='{0}'>", GetImageUrl(item.Code), item.Code)));
```

This will render fine, but on post back I get the following error:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

I understand the error. The question is; how do I dynamical add images to my RadioButtonList without causing this error?

I have also tried to `HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode` the img string, but that renders the literal text and not the image.

As a note, I do **not** want to set `EnableEventValidation="false"`, as this will leave my page open to nefarious activity.

This question seems to related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645245/radiobuttonlist-with-image-throwing-xxs-error-on-postback), but its not marked as answered.

Answer (score 0):

message `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client` comes whenever you try to pass html string via post in asp.net

Your best way to do is encode string into base64 and than decode it while showing into form and while posting form's data back just convert all html related data into base64 string via jquery or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this occurs is the html code for the image is being sent across in the post back. You can disable validation on the RadioButtonList by adding  ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" [validaterequestmode(v=vs.110)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.validaterequestmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RlCredtiCardTypes" runat="server" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"></asp:RadioButtonList>
```

This will leave the rest of your form securely checking against evil code.